# Filter inner keys from 2 level nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I looking the most elegant way to get this:

```
{'i_1': {'a': 33, 't': 4}, 'i_2': {'a': 9, 't': 0}}
```

From this:

```
{'i_1': {'a': 33, 'b': 55, 't': 4}, 'i_2': {'a': 9, 'b': 11, 't': 0}}
```

Each inner dict can have a lot of a, b, ..., z keys.

for now I have this::

```
In [3]: {k:dict(a=d[k]['a'], t=d[k]['t']) for k in d.keys()}
Out[3]: {'i_1': {'a': 33, 't': 4}, 'i_2': {'a': 9, 't': 0}}
```

but it's not very elegant

Comment: So you want to recursively search dictionaries and remove all `'b'` keys?

Comment: it's more to select 3 different keys from a ~20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your code a little bit more readable by using `items` instead of `keys`:

```
{k: dict(a=v['a'], t=v['t']) for k, v in d.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy

def foo(d):
    d_copy = copy.deepcopy(d)

    for key in d_copy:
        print(key, d[key])
        if isinstance(d[key], dict):
            foo(d[key])
        if key == 'b':
            d.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This functions takes a dict in a format you specified and a list of keys that have to be removed from inner dictionaries:

```
def remove_inner_keys(data: dict, inner_keys_to_remove: list) -> dict:
    result = dict()

    for outer_key in data.keys():
        partial_result = dict()
        for inner_key in data[outer_key]:
            if inner_key not in inner_keys_to_remove:
                partial_result[inner_key] = data[outer_key][inner_key]
        result[outer_key] = partial_result

    return result
```

Testing:

```
data = { 'i_1': { 'a': 33, 'b': 55, 't': 4 }, 'i_2': { 'a': 9, 'b': 11, 't': 0 } }
print(str(remove_inner_keys(data, ["b"])))
```

output:

```
{'i_2': {'a': 9, 't': 0}, 'i_1': {'a': 33, 't': 4}}
```